# If we have a coin toss, would this proof be considered as an Almost sure convergence proof?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, convergence-divergence, random

If we have $n$ coin tosses and we want to prove that the coin will *eventually* land heads, will this proof be considered a proof of a.s convergence?

Let's consider a contracting sequence of events $A_1, A_2,\ldots A_n$ where A is an event that heads don't fall on the current iteration (T, TT, TTT, ...), then the probability $P(A_1 \cap A_2\cap \ldots A_n= \lim_{n\to\infty}P(A_n)=0$ and then take the complement. I am trying to understand what would count as an a.s proof and, for now, I am just confused.

Comment: The thing you could say is that the random variable $1_{A_n}$ converges almost surely to $0$. Is that what you mean ?

Comment: Hint: Borel-Cantelli I

Comment: @Snoop I thought of Borel Cantelli too, let's say I prove a.s convergence to 0 for events $A_n$ would taking the complement after that be correct? If I want to prove that the coin will eventually land a.s.

Comment: @SuspiciousFred Yes, something like that. The end goal is to prove that the probability of a coin landing heads in $n$ flips converges to 1 a.s. But I am also curious about the proof i mentioned and its correctness.

Comment: @ТимурБирюков, the _probability_ does not converge almost surely, it converges. The things that converge a.s. are the random variables. Is that a source of confusion ?